# I'm decompiling an apk file to learn how the creator designed the UI for their app. Are these layout files obfuscated?

Tags: obfuscation, android, deobfuscation, decompile, apk

I'm new to decompiling apps. Most of the apps I decompile aren't very popular, so obfuscation hasn't been a problem yet. I'm not entirely sure what obfuscation looks like. The current app I'm looking into has this, or a similar variant, in all of its layout files.

> RelativeLayout      ImageView LinearLayout !!com.graphtech.views.AppsViewPager  € @   ô õ Ô Ä Ð s× &¯ Õ         ÿÿÿÿ       t      ÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿ                  ÿÿÿÿ           ÿÿÿÿ  1        ÿÿÿÿ  ÿÿÿÿ      ÿÿÿÿ  ÿÿÿÿ œ      ÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿ                  ÿÿÿÿ   
>          ÿÿÿÿ  ÿÿÿÿ      ÿÿÿÿ  ÿÿÿÿ      ÿÿÿÿ           ÿÿÿÿ  ÿÿÿÿ

Is this obfuscation or just a problem from the process of decompiling?

A lot of weird symbols.

The app I'm looking into is the "Else Splay Launcher". It's the leftovers from an unsuccessful phone ui a company designed some years ago, and it was eventually turned into a launcher for Android.

[Splay Launcher UI Preview](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1TURvkvrJ-Q)

Answer (score 1):

You see weird symbols, because you opened a binary file with a text viewer. The XML files are Android XMLs (XML files compressed by the Android AAPT tool) and you can find a lot of tools how you can [decompress/view](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4191762/how-to-view-androidmanifest-xml-from-apk-file) them.